# Android ~ Why does FragmentPageAdapter clear my Layout's TabItem icon?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The following is within my main activity's layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/settingsButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_mic_black_36dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder_black_36dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

If i do nothing but run my code containing the above the TabItem will show icons but the moment i set the TabLayout to have a FragmentPageAdapter the icons disappear leaving a blank space.

The following is my FragmentPageAdpater:

```
public class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
    {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why when i go to **tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);** the icons now disappear?  I only show icons not text.  There are only 2 fragments being added and so there are only 2 blank tabs being shown.

Comment: Can you share activity code for setting adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TabLayout.setupWithViewPager()` will eventually call through to `TabLayout.populateFromPagerAdapter()`, which in turn will call `TabLayout.removeAllTabs()`. After that, it will create *new* tabs using the `ViewPager`'s page titles:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
>     addTab(newTab().setText(mPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)), false);
> }
> ```

As such, the `<TabItem>` tags in your layout are simply thrown away and replaced.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution i decided to add the following into my main activity's onCreate()

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mic_black_36dp);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_folder_black_36dp);
```

The last 2 lines added the icons to my blank tabs.  They must be applied AFTER the setupWithViewPager call.